# Converting a 0 - 6 scale to a 0 - 10 scale in a linear fashion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a scale between 0-6, and say, a value of 4. How would I stretch the scale to 0-10 without skewing the results. In other words, how would I stretch the result without it being logarithmic?

Comment: Multiply by $10/6$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: if $G$ denotes your grade in the $0-6$ system, and $NG$ denoted the new grade in the $0-10$ system, then you want:

$$\frac{G}{6} = \frac{GN}{10}.$$

Solving for $GN$ gives you

$$GN=\frac{10G}{6}.$$

Thus, if you received $G=4$ in your old scale, in the new scale the grade would be $\frac{10 \cdot 4}{6} \approx 6.67$